# How could I bulk delete docs using a custom type field with NEST for Elastic?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

How would I go upon using BulkDeleteDescriptor to delete documents that match a certain criteria using Elastic's NEST?

Specifically, I have a custom type field and I want to delete all docs that have a specific type and any other criteria such as ID, a document would look like this:

```
{
  "_index": "testIndex",
  "_id": "someId",
  "_score": 1.0,
  "_source": {
    "bookName": "A Book",
    "type": "action"
  }
}
```

When Elastic/NEST had types, I would do this:

```
descriptor.Delete<object>(i => i
    .Index("testIndex") 
    .Type(type)
    .Id(id));
```

Can't seem to find much on NEST documentation..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bulk delete is a great way to delete a bunch of documents when you have ids of these documents upfront. For a case when you don't know ids, I would suggest [delete by query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) which will delete documents matching query criteria.

With this API you will be able to specify both delete criteria (id and type) at the same time

```
POST your_index/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
        {
            "term": {
                "_id": x
            }
        },
        {
            "term": {
                "type": y
            }
        }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah I misunderstood with my previous comment, I see what I have to do. Does NEST have any documentation on how this is done? I think I have an idea what the Query on the C# side would look like but I'm not sure..

Comment: @sm0keman1 There isn't NEST specific documentation for `DeleteByQuery`. One way to be sure that the query is correct is to first use the search API or count API to check that the expected number of documents and the documents look correct for the query, before using it in the delete by query API

Comment: Thank you! I figured it out and it seems to work like a charm :)